# Should I worry for this number of Aborted clients & connects?

Tags: mysql

I am getting below number of Aborted clients & connects

```
mysqladmin ext | grep Abort
```

Which results as:

```
| Aborted_clients                               | 719          |
| Aborted_connects                              | 4458         |
```

One thing to note is, I am getting frequent "MySQL Server has gone away" error.
Not sure if above number of Aborted-** can cause the

> MySQL Server has gone away

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Those are counters; they are useless without dividing by `Uptime` or `Connections`.  I would say something is wrong if

```
Aborted_clients / Uptime > 0.3 / second
Aborted_connects / Uptime > 1 / second
Aborted_clients / Connections > 30%
Aborted_connects / Connections > 8%
```

If you exceed any of these *guidelines*, look into

- making sure that your clients do disconnect, and/or
- increasing `max_connections` (but not too much), and/or
- increasing `wait_timeout`

"gone away" comes from network glitches and/or trying to hang onto a connection "too long".  See the various `%wait_timeout` settings.